# Perl string if/or comparison operator

Tags: perl, if-statement, operators, conditional-statements

Why is the following code:

```
# Get new_status
print STDERR "Please enter status value (active/inactive): ";
ReadMode(1);
my $new_status = ReadLine(0);
ReadMode(0);
print STDERR "\n";

if ( ($new_status ne "active") || ($new_status ne "inactive") )
{
  die "Status must be active/inactive.";
}
```

will always return "Status must be active/inactive." no matter what I type? (active, inactive, or anything else, or even just press enter.)

The code appears to be valid:

- I clearly separate both statement with brackets
- I use the string
  operator "ne" in both cases
- I use the OR operator ||

There's obviously something about Perl operators I am not fully grasping. 
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you !

Answer (score -5, accepted):

So I found the answer to my question.

The issue is with formatting.

I added:

```
print Dumper $new_status;
```

in my code and the output was:

```
$VAR1 = 'active
';
```

So I added a :

```
chomp $new_status;
```

and now its working perfectly.

```
$VAR1 = 'active';
```

Final code:

```
# Get new_status
print STDERR "Please enter status value (active/inactive): ";
ReadMode(1);
my $new_status = ReadLine(0);
ReadMode(0);
print STDERR "\n";

chomp $new_status;

unless ( ($new_status eq "active") || ($new_status eq "inactive") )
{
  die "Status must be active/inactive.";
}
```

Comment: And you replace the `if` with an `unless`, that's definitely not a detail.

Comment: Actually, they made they made three relevant changes: if→unless, ne→eq, ne→eq (The change in formatting is not relevant.)

Answer (score 2):

`$new_status` can't be equal to `active` and `inactive` at the same time, so condition is always true. You probably need `&&` instead of `||`

Choose any option that looks more intuitive to you:

```
# option 1
if ( ($new_status ne "active") && ($new_status ne "inactive") )
...
# option 2
unless ( ($new_status eq "active") || ($new_status eq "inactive") )
...
#option 3
my %VALID_STATUS = (
    'active' => 1,
    'inactive' => 1,
);
if (!$VALID_STATUS{$new_status})
...
```

Comment: I down voted that answer because you're assuming I don't know the difference between AND or OR, and that I am trying to get a status that is both active and inactive which is not the case.

Comment: @Bluz Well, you actually used an `||` instead of a `&&`... I mean, this isn't a big deal: it has happened to pretty much everybody. But this answer is correct, and there is definitely no justification for downvoting it.

Comment: Please don't use `unless` for anything but trivial checks; having to distribute an implicit negation confuses too many people.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( ($new_status ne "active") || ($new_status ne "inactive") )
{
  die "Status must be active/inactive.";
}
```

Let's work through the logic.

1. I type something random (let's use `random`). `random` isn't "active" and isn't "inactive", so your `if` clause becomes `if (true or true)` - which is true.
2. I type `active`. That's false on the first check and true on the second check, so you get `if (false or true)` - which is true.
3. I type `inactive`. That's true on the first check and false on the second, so you get `if (true or false)` - which is true.

There is nothing you can enter that makes your `if` statement false.

Your problem that you don't want to join your two clauses with `or`, you should use `and` instead.

(And take a tip from this old programmer - using `and` and `or` instead of `&&` and `||` for flow control will be far less confusing.)

**Update:** All in all, there are too many negatives in your code and you're confusing yourself. In your answer, you (silently!) change the `if` to an `unless`, thereby making the code even harder to follow for a maintenance programmer.

I'd write it like this:

```
my $valid = $new_status eq 'active' || $new_status eq 'inactive';
if (not $valid) {
   die "...";
}
```

Or like this:

```
use List::Util 'any';

if (not any { $new_status eq $_ } qw[active inactive] ) {
  die "...";
}
```

Comment: Please don't recommend the use of `not`/`or`/`and` outside of flow control (`or die`, `or last`, `or return`, etc). It leads to errors such as the one I had to fix in your answer.

Comment: @ikegami: Damn. You're right. Ignoring my own best practice there. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

You only want to display the error message if `$new_status` isn't `active` *AND* if `$new_status` isn't `inactive`, so

```
if ( $new_status ne "active" || $new_status ne "inactive" )
```

should be

```
if ( $new_status ne "active" && $new_status ne "inactive" )
```

---

We can prove this. Remember [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

- `!( A || B )` is equivalent to `!A && !B`.
- `!( A && B )` is equivalent to `!A || !B`.

So,

- Valid input if `$new_status eq 'active' || $new_status eq 'inactive'`
- Invalid input if `!( $new_status eq 'active' || $new_status eq 'inactive' )`
- Invalid input if `!( $new_status eq 'active' ) && !( $new_status eq 'inactive' )`
- Invalid input if `$new_status ne 'active' && $new_status ne 'inactive'`

---

You will need to become accustomed to seeing the following:

```
if ( $new_status ne "active" && $new_status ne "inactive" ) {
   die("Status must be active/inactive.\n");
}
```

But you might prefer to use an assertive style of coding instead.

```
$new_status eq "active" || $new_status eq "inactive"    # Thing that should be true.
   or die("Status must be active/inactive.\n");         # Or what to do when it isn't.
```